# Multiple Event Attendance look up on excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want to create a table in excel that lists the people who have bought tickets to more than one of our event and have it state how many events they have bought tickets to.

I have a large spreadsheet with all the tickets sold for multiple events that my company has held.  Each ticket has the details of the person who bought them in the form of email address and name, as well as which event it was.

Is there a way I can use a pivot table to list the multiple events attendees as well how many event they have attended?

Comment: COUNTIFS() may work but some example data would help refine options.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using the Distinct Count option for summarizing your data in the pivottable. For this option to be available, you need to add your table to the datamodel. You can check this option when you insert your pivot table.

[image]

In your pivottable put Name one rows and Event on Values. In the Value Field Settings dialog choose Distinct Count (the last option).

[image]